# How can I test the push function of an official account without an official account?

Tags: testing, push-notification, wechat, wechat-official-account

I developed a function for WeChat push configuration, but here I need to test whether the push to the official account is normal, but Party A did not provide the official account, so I can only test it myself, but I don’t know how to test it. I hope everyone can give you suggestions and try not to make too many changes to the original code.

I thought this would be simple, but I needed a server to do it.
Using public accounts for testing requires development from scratch. Is there any convenient and efficient method?